# Perform union on structure objects of same type in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have two structure objects of the same type and would like to know if there's a way to perform union on them to yield one structure object if data members may be NOTHING in one of the IQueryables. How should I handle possible empty results(either or both Qy1/Qy2) and still able to merge them without knowing the outcome in advance. Thanks in advance!

```
Structure MyStrut 
    public DMem1 As String 
    public DMem2 As String 
End Structure

Dim Qy1 As IQueryable(Of Mystrut) 
Dim Qy2 As IQueryable(Of Mystrut) 
Dim QyUnion As IQueryable(Of Mystrut)

Qy1 = from q1 In query1 select new MyStrut{.DMem1 = Nothing, .DMem2=q1.txtField2}

Qy2 = from q2 In query2 select new MyStrut{.DMem1 = q2.txtField1, .DMem2=Nothing}

QyUnion = (From x In Qy1 select x).Concat(From y In Qy2 select y)
```

Comment: Have you tried .Union statement? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on your own here - what you're asking for (if I understand what you're asking) really can't be automatically predicted, so I think you'll need to write a method like:

```
Public Function Combine(input As IEnumerable(Of MyStruct)) As MyStruct
    Dim result As New MyStruct()
    For Each s As MyStruct In input
        If (result.DMem1 Is Nothing AndAlso s.DMem1 IsNot Nothing) Then
            result.DMem1 = s.DMem1
        End If
        If (result.DMem2 Is Nothing AndAlso s.DMem2 IsNot Nothing) Then
            result.DMem2 = s.DMem2
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was thinking that the datamembers may be set to the default values for the respective datatype of the data members. So the union'ed iQueryable of (Mystruct) will have Row(0) Dmem1=Nothing; Dmem2 = txtField2, Row(1) Dmem1=txtField1; Dmem2=txtField2 . For all intensive purpose, I can default them by hardcoding the Nothings to String.Empty My problem is even when I do that my new QyUnion doesn't have any rows, any idea why?

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly what you want. I thought you wanted to take a collection of items and combine them into one, populating as many properties as you could. What you're describing is taking two collections and combining them into one collection and at the same time combining the individual objects. Maybe you could expand on your question by providing a real-world example, and it might be easier to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the union of them simply by

```
QyUnion = Qy1.Union(Qy2)
```

No need here for the from and select, particularly if you are just selecting the full object. In fact, Unlike C#, VB doesn't require any ending select. Thus the following is perfectly valid as well:

```
QyUnion = from a in Qy1.
          Union(from b in Qy2)
```

Although, I don't know why one would take the extra effort here when the first example is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks Jim for your tips